# Using addContentView to break my large layout file into mutiple smaller layout files?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one main layout file, which has grown excessively large and is getting quite hard to read. I currently just use setContentView(int layoutResID) to inflate the whole layout.

I recently discovered the addContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) method, and I want some input from others before I waste any time making significant changes.

My main layout file looks something like this at the moment:

```
frame layout
    relative layout
        ...
    linear layout a
        ...
    linear layout b
        ...
    linear layout c
        ...
    linear layout d
        ...
    linear layout e
        ...
/frame layout
```

Where some of the linear layouts are very complex.

My question is, if I separate each of the complex linear layouts into their own xml files, then successively inflate each of them using addContentView, will I end up with the same behaviour as my current implementation with setContentView ?

My main motivation is for each separate layout file to contain just one of the complex linear layouts, for easier readability of the xml files.

Comment: Your structure sounds singularly bizarre. That being said, I'd recommend `<include>` over `addContentView()`: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: When I first started working on the app, I didn't anticipate that the layout would get so complex, which is why I didn't break it down into multiple layouts until now. 
I didn't know about the <include> technique, thank you!

Comment: As i can see you are using multiple linear layout, you can use custom ListView instead.

Comment: I should have mentioned that each of the linear layouts a, b, c, d, and e are all totally different to one another, and only one of them is ever visible at one time. That's why I want to separate them into different layout files, even though my layout behaviour is already working perfectly in my app. Anyway, I think the <include> idea should work fine for what I hope to achieve. 
I learned a lot about layouts while working on this app, and I would have done it properly from the start if I had known better at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You could also inflate these different layouts by using Layout Inflater. and add those inflated views in your frame layout dynamically. For eg

```
 View v;
 if(condition){
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.a)
 }
else if(condition){
   v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.b)
}

FrameLayout f= findviewbyId(R.id.frameLayout)
f.addView(v);
```

Comment: Thanks newBie, that's another good tip. 
I ended up using the <include> technique last night, and it worked nicely.